# npm: How to initalize AndroidPublisher from googleapis

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, google-developers-console, google-play-developer-api

How can I initialize the Android publisher to access the google play developer API? I know that I can use the raw `googleapis` package but my server is running out of memory when importing that package thus I used the `@googleapis/androidpublisher` package the only I need.

I don't know how to pass proper 'auth' to the publisher so I can authenticate adequately. I am using the Service account credentials file as mentioned in the google readme:

[image]

This code does not work.

```js
import { androidpublisher_v3 as AndroidPublisherApi } from "@googleapis/androidpublisher";
import credentials from "../assets/google-play-console-service-account.json";

this.androidPublisher = new AndroidPublisherApi.Androidpublisher({
  auth: new GoogleAuth(
    {
      credentials, // Pass in the 'google-play-console-service-account.json' credentials
      scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"],
    })
});
```

> The expected type comes from property 'auth' which is declared here on type 'GlobalOptions'

> Type 'GoogleAuth' is not assignable to type 'string | BaseExternalAccountClient | GoogleAuth | OAuth2Client | undefined'.
> Type 'GoogleAuth' is not assignable to type 'GoogleAuth'.
> Types have separate declarations of a private property 'checkIsGCE'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This needs to be done as mentioned here: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/tasks/

```js
const publisher = require("@googleapis/androidpublisher");

const auth = new publisher.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFilename: './api/assets/google-play-console-service-account.json',
  // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single, space-delimited string.
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"]
});
this.androidPublisher = new publisher.androidpublisher_v3.Androidpublisher({ auth: auth })
```

Comment: eslint will show 'Typescript : require statement not part of an import statement' error  for the first line. You can put  /* eslint-disable */   tags before and after that line to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I did it using typescript and firebase cloud functions:

```js
import {androidpublisher_v3 as AndroidPublisherV3, google} from'googleapis';

async getAndroidPublisher(): Promise<AndroidPublisherV3.Androidpublisher> {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: 'src/keys/myServiceKey.json',
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'],
  });
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();
  google.options({auth: authClient});
  this.androidPublisher = google.androidpublisher('v3');
  return this.androidPublisher;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing file path like this:

```
keyFilename: './api/assets/google-play-console-service-account.json',
```

does not work and causes the following error even though the file is there and path is correct:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ...
```

Alternate way is to pass values without using keyFilename like below:

```
credentials: {
    client_email: "EnterValueHere", // client_email value from your google-play-console-service-account.json
    private_key: "EnterValueHere", // private_key value from your google-play-console-service-account.json
    },
```